# Python raw_input with forced TLD?

Tags: python, regex, raw-input, tld

I am working on a program that checks hostnames of specific sites, and I want to be able to insure that when asked for the hostname (with `raw_input`) it ends in a TLD (`.com`, `.net`, `.org`). I am not exactly sure how to do this in Python.

In bash I have:

```
local TLD=(com info org net)    
for entry in ${TLD[@]}; do
   blah blah    
done
```

What is the equivalent in Python?

Comment: (Edited for some formatting.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`endswith(suffix[, start[, end]])` will do the trick. [Documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/string-methods.html)

Please also note that suffix can be a tuple of suffices!

```
TLD = ('.com', '.info', '.org', '.net')
if raw_input("Please enter a hostname").endswith(TLD):
    # blah blah
```

Comment: +1. Nice answer. He'll probably need to save the `raw_input` though.

Comment: You might also consider using `.lower().endswith(TLD)` to allow for UPPER CASE.

Comment: Geoff is correct, I do in fact want to store raw_input. I attempted to do that with a tmpvar list, but I keep getting broken conditionals. What would be the best way to capture that input, if it doesn't match the TLD, have it ask again, otherwise when the input is correct have it continue on with the program? I attempted to do a while True: loop with a list for the variable but I can't break the loop.

Comment: @Jacob What do you mean by broken conditionals? Do you want to keep store all of the non-matching TLD inputs as well?

Comment: @user1850672 I asked a secondary question and was given the answer :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16822171/python-code-to-determine-if-tld-exists-prompt-again-if-not